# Flask user management

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Is there any way to check when user was last logged in and if this time period is longer then x flask will block an account? Is it possible with flask and how to handle event listener to do so?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to add timestamp to user model but still can't find the way to make flask check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `before_request` callback to check the last login date for the current user and return an error if it is too old.  This assumes your user model has a `last_login_on` field that is has a `datetime` value that is updated when the user logs in.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from flask_login import current_user

@app.before_request
def check_login_age():
    # check if older than 30 days
    if current_user.last_login_on < datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(30):
        # do something to block it
        abort(401)
```